# nodejs - Bash-like stdin

Tags: node.js, stdin

I'd like to emulate the bash input behaviour (e.g. press up arrow to access the input history, Ctrl+C to cancel input, Ctrl+D to quit).

But if I want to escape arrow keys for example (which by default are replaced by ^[[A, ^[[B, ^[[C and ^[[D), I need to set the *raw mode* on, and then, input events are fired each time a key is pressed. This is useful, but then I need to hard code the basic input behavior like return key or delete key...

So is there a way, maybe by piping a stream on stdin, to access input both in raw mode and non raw mode ?

Comment: Maybe this helps you https://github.com/thlorenz/readline-vim

Comment: It uses the [REPL](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html) module that looks interesting, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is the `readline` module ([doc](http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html)). It provides an input history, an autocompletion (on tab hit), etc.

Example :

```
var readline = require('readline');

var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input : process.stdin,
    output : process.stdout,
});

function input (prompt, callback) {
    rl.question(prompt, function (res) {
        if (res === 'quit') rl.close();
        else callback(res);
    });
}
```

An example of Command Line Interface is given [here](http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_example_tiny_cli) in the doc

Answer (score 0):

What you might be looking for is the [`rs.setRawMode(mode)`](http://nodejs.org/api/tty.html#tty_rs_setrawmode_mode) for the native `TTY` modules. Originally in Node v0.8.x, there was a undocumented `keypress` event for `process.stdin` that would emit when it was a TTY. It was then altered to only fire when being used with `readline`, so I would suggest using that.

The functionality is still accessible by a module called [`keypress`](https://github.com/TooTallNate/keypress). It was directly taken from Node source, and is used like so (taken from documentation):

```
var keypress = require('keypress');

// make `process.stdin` begin emitting "keypress" events
keypress(process.stdin);

// listen for the "keypress" event
process.stdin.on('keypress', function (ch, key) {
  console.log('got "keypress"', key);
  if (key && key.ctrl && key.name == 'c') {
    process.stdin.pause();
  }
});

process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
process.stdin.resume();
```

It's also been altered to support a `mousepress` event that you will also find on the GitHub page.

Comment: But if *raw mode* is on, the `data` event of stdin is fired for each keypress and the special keys, like return, delete or the left and right arrows are not handled any more.

Comment: The keypress module handles those keys as well.